# Does there exist a perfect group with a subgroup of index at most 4?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Does there exist a finite perfect group with a subgroup of index at most 4?

Comment: Yes, $A_5$ has a subgroup of index 1.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1) $\,G\,$ is perfect iff $\,G':=[G,G]=G\,$

2) For *any* group $\,K\,$ , if it has a subgroup $\,H\,$ of index n then it has a *normal* subgroup of index dividing $\,n!\,$ and, in fact, this normal subgroup is contained in $\,H\,$

3) Every group of order less than $\,5\,$ is abelian

4) For any group $\,T\,$ , if $\,N\lhd T\,$  then the quotient $\,T/N\,$ is abelian iff $\,T'\leq N\,$